# Is using backticks necessary?

Tags: sql, mysql

When I write an SQL statement, I usually write it like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM catalogsearch_query AS main_table
```

But I found that some people write SQL statements like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `catalogsearch_query` AS `main_table`
```

Do I have to use `` ` ``?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use backticks. However when you're using reserved keywords as table or field names, then you have to enclose them in backticks for them to work.

Answer (score 0):

From [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html) docs:

> Database, table, index, column, and alias names are identifiers. An identifier ***may*** be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you ***must*** quote it whenever you refer to it.

We use the backtick **`** for quoting.